# Comparing 2 Text Files for Differences, Output Summary of Differences in a Log File

Tags: c#, text-files, diff

So I have 6 different text files and I want to compare one with another based on what the user has selected to be compared. My program already compares the text files and gives an the outputs of if the text files are the same or if they are different. I want to now be able to add the functionality of it saying on which line numbers it is different, and what characters have been added/taken away.

I initialised the string arrays as such:

```
string[] texta;
string[] textb;
string[] textc;
```

etc.

Assume that the string[] arrays already have the text in them as I have done it myself as such:

`texta = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"texta.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader obj1;
            StreamReader obj2;

            obj1 = new StreamReader(@"texta.txt");
            obj2 = new StreamReader(@"textb.txt");


            string Text1;
            string Text2;
            int line=0;
            while (!obj1.EndOfStream || !obj2.EndOfStream)
            {
                Text1 = obj1.ReadLine();
                Text2 = obj2.ReadLine();

                if (Text1 != Text2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    line++;
            }

            // line = line Nr. not the same
```